# No Print assistant in DigiKam 5.4.0

Tags: digikam

I have DigiKam 5.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.
The sub-menu options `print` and `print assistant` are missing from the `Item` drop-down menu at the top, it ends at `Edit Geolocation`.

I have looked at FAQ and Google but not found how to restore it, please does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need kipi-plugins:

```
sudo apt install kipi-plugins
```

Comment: You might want to expand on your answer.  Will simply installing this plugin restore the menu as the OP requires, or are any additional steps (e.g. configuration) needed?

Comment: No, this will do the trick (at least it did for me).